# GridView OnRowCommand not fired the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This probably looks like a duplicate but I don't think so. I have already searched stackoverflow, may be not enough.

Here is my challenge:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DeleteRow" CommandName="deleterow" 
   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="Delete" 
   OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" />
```

If you click the link the first time, OnRowCommand is not fired. When you click it the second time, it works.

I looked at the source and I have these differences.

```
//When you first load the page: the GUID is the PK for that row 
1. javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$content$gvSchoolClasses$58fd1759-f358-442e-bf73-2e9cedfc27e8$DeleteRow','')

//After the link was clicked the first time, the link changed and the ID empty, but works
2. javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$content$gvSchoolClasses$ctl02$DeleteRow','')
```

I copied the two codes from the `href` of the `asp:LinkButton` for BEFORE and AFTER click.

What is wrong? I only have one other event on my page `RowDataBound`.

```
  protected void gvSchoolClasses_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
        e.Row.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        CheckAuthentication();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ClassesAcademicYearLabel.Text = "- Year " + Setting.Year;
            //FillClassesList();  //filling some combo boxes. Have checked the codes here too
            //FillLettersList();  //they didn't affect the Grid
            FillGrid();
        }

        ClassErrorLabel.Visible = false;

  }
```

Comment: mind sharing your `RowDataBound` event handling code? I'm curious as to why you've excluded it as a problem source

Comment: I believe the code inside should not affect the linkButton. that was affecting the Grid

Comment: where is `gvSchoolClasses.DataBind()` being called? `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the ID property of the row in the `RowDataBound` event, you've created the problem you're observing.

Since the `RowDataBound` event isn't fired until after the page's controls have already been added to the collection, ASP.NET doesn't have a way to update the already-computed client references. Hence, the command doesn't get fired in the way you're expecting.

I've noticed that you're already setting the `CommandArgument` property to the ID generated in the `RowDataBound` event, which could also be part of your problem (depends on order of events firing; I don't have a pipeline chart handy).

EDIT: a quick fix for this could be to simply set the ClientID properties (sorry, not the exact name, but intellisense should get you the rest of the way to it) to some sort of Manual, not Auto determination. That way, the ID you set is never changed by the framework.

To elaborate a bit more on why you're seeing this problem, consider the client-side id's presented:

`ctl00$content$gvSchoolClasses$ctl02$DeleteRow`

This ID is guaranteed to be unique (for this page) by taking the declared ID (`DeleteRow`) and successively walking UP the control hierarchy and prepending parent ID's to the string. JS code can be confident that passing this string to `getElementById` will behave in a consistent, predictable manner.

In order to be able to generate said ID, all of the controls in the hierarchy must already be present and accounted for by the rendering engine.

Now let's consider what happens when that the ID property of a control is changed (note this is not the `ClientID`, but simply the property with a name of `ID`).

`ctl00$content$gvSchoolClasses$58fd1759-f358-442e-bf73-2e9cedfc27e8$DeleteRow`

You'll note that instead of the row's naming container (`cl02`), it now has the GUID you generated and assigned to it. Client JS attempting to access this container using the previously assigned ID will be disappointed, since it will no longer work as expected!

When an ASP.NET control fires a post-back via a call to `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$content$gvSchoolClasses$58fd1759-f358-442e-bf73-2e9cedfc27e8$DeleteRow','')`

the post-back will occur just fine and dandy, but (and you can verify this by inspecting the form params of the postback) when the server processes the request, it will attempt to rehydrate (from viewstate) a control that doesn't exist. Consequently, it will create a new instance of the control (with the correct ID) which has no idea that a command has been issued, so the `XXXCommand` event(s) are never fired. Since databinding isn't happening (it's a postback, and your code correctly checks for that condition), the ID is never reset, and the command can be fired normally

Comment: removing the e.Row.ID from the RowDataBound works. I think the explanation would be that the introduced `Guid.NewGuid` was messing with the expected string in the postback method. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I wanted to ask for this, but I felt like I would google it.

Comment: Brilliant and Perfect explanation

Answer (score 1):

don't change the Row.ID in your RowDataBound event.  Either change a different value in the grid or just do this in your gridview markup:

CommandArgument='<%: Guid.NewGuid.ToString(); %>'

If you wanted to do it in code behind you could do something like this:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton deleteRow = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("DeleteRow");
            if (deleteRow != null)
                deleteRow.CommandArgument = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
```

Comment: It was a piece of code for row editing I left unused and I changed to what you just suggested `<%: Guid.NewGuid.ToString(); %>`. So it was redundant now causing trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Row Index to the CommandArgument of the Link Button not the guid

As you said it work in the second time but the html is as shown below

```
//After the link was clicked the first time, the link changed and the ID empty, but works
2. javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$content$gvSchoolClasses$ctl02$DeleteRow','')
```